# How to write query for a has many relationship that has no matches on an attribute?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using Ruby on Rails 7.0.4 with Active Record and mysql.

I have 2 models: a Post and a Tag. A Post has many Tags. A Tag belongs to one Post. The Tag has a "Name" attribute that is a string.

My page is loading several posts. It also contains a list of several Tags that I want to filter out, and this list is passed via url query params. For example, let's say it has been parsed to ["pop", "metal", "blues"], and this is stored in a variable called `tag_list`.

The tricky thing is that for this functionality I need to only show posts that are NOT tagged with ANY of the incoming names in the list.

If I was looking for a match, it would be easy to do a `where in`:

```
Post.left_outer_joins(:tags).where(tags: {name: tag_list})
```

The above says "If a post has any tags that match anything in the tag list, return the post." But I need the opposite. First thought would be a `where.not`:

```
Post.left_outer_joins(:tags).where.not(tags: {name: tag_list})
```

However, this says "If any of a post's tags do not match, then the post is valid - return it." For example, if the tag_list is ["pop", "metal", "blues"] and a post is tagged with ["pop", "metal", "folk"] it will still be returned because "folk" != "blues". I would only want posts where there are NO matches, such as ["neo-classical", "punk"] - no pop, metal or blues.

The other tricky thing is that this is chained onto a scope that uses a `left_outer_joins` because I also need to return posts that have no tags (optional has_many). And because of this I have been running into issues with this error `ArgumentError (Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]):`.

Also just a disclaimer that this is a condensed example, not the exact code because I am under an NDA.

Comment: `Post.where.not(id: Tag.where(name: tag_list).select(:post_id))`

Comment: Chances are there is a join table in between creating a HABTM but @AbM's suggestion should get you there.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had to do a bunch of testing to make sure this would work. But yes, @AbM your suggestion was exactly what I needed! Thank you! If you want to make it an answer to the question I'll officially accept it as the answer.